# graph.intersection does not work in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Here is an example:

```
df1 <- graph.data.frame(V1=c(1,1,2,2,3,4), V2=c(2,3,3,5,5,5))
g1 <- graph.data.frame(df1, directed=F)
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,2,3,4), V2=c(3,3,5,5,5))
g2 <- graph.data.frame(df2, directed=F)
df3 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4), V2=c(3,3,5,5))
g3 <- graph.data.frame(df3, directed=F)
df4 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,1,2,3), V2=c(2,3,4,5))
g4 <- graph.data.frame(df4, directed=F)
```

Now create a list

```
mylist <- list(g1, g2, g3, g4)
```

And now look for the intersection

```
  res <- intersection(mylist, keep.all.vertices=FALSE)
```

But I got this weird result:

```
  Error in useMethod(intersection): no applicable method for 'intersection' applied to an object of class list
```

Any help with be appreciated, I am using `igraph version 1.0.1`

Comment: Instead,  just use  `intersection(g1,g2,g3,g4, keep.all.vertices=FALSE)`

Comment: yep, that works, but i have 700 graphs and they state in the manual `... 
Graph objects or lists of graph objects.` so I wanted to know if it is a bug or something with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems like a bit of a hack, but you can get the functionality that you are looking for with:

```
do.call(intersection, c(mylist, keep.all.vertices=FALSE))
```